# Javascript: Get selected option from list and paste it on a label tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, html, label

I have a list of countries, html, they have numeric ids and country name:

Ex:

```
<select name="userDto.nationality" id="userDto.nationality">
            <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                <option value="1">Alemania</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="2">Argentina</option>
                <option value="8">Australia</option>
                <option value="9">Austria</option>
                <option value="10">Bélgica</option>
                <option value="11">Bolivia</option>
</select>
```

Im trying to use a jquery script to get the country of the list, not the value, the name and paste it inside of a label.

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $("#userDto\\.nationality option:selected").click(function() { $("#nationalityLabel").html(this.value); });

});
```

And the HTML that should get the country name is:

```
<div name="userLabelDiv" id="nationalityUserLabelDiv">
    <label class="required">Nacionalidad :</label>
    <label id="nationalityLabel"></label> 
</div>
```

Could someone guide me through the problem? I cant find where is my error in the JS code.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two little things:

- change selector from `$("#userDto\\.nationality option:selected")` 
  to `$("#userDto\\.nationality")`
- change event handler from `click` to `change`

Done.

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
   $("#userDto\\.nationality").change(function() { 
      $("#nationalityLabel").html(this.value);
   });
});
```

Why:

Your current code would have worked, but only for "Argentinia" since it is `selected` by default. With your selector `option:selected` you bound the event handler only to selected option elements, which is, Argentinia.

So you need to add an event handler to the `select element` itself. The change handler fires whenever you change the selection. I guess that is your desired result.

Comment: This is working, but my label is getting the id of the option, example: I select "Austria" from the select list and my label shows the id "9", but I actually need it to showme the name of the country that corresponds to the id, in this case, I need the label to show me "Austria". How can I trick that? Thank you!